# Using WSDL service from Python, it is my client code or the server?

Tags: python, wsdl, soap-client, suds

I'm trying to write a Python client for a a WSDL service. I'm using the [Suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) library to handle the SOAP messages.

When I try to call the service, I get a Suds exception: `<rval />` not mapped to message part. If I set the `retxml` Suds option I get XML which looks OK to me.

Is the problem with the client code? Am I missing some flag which will allow Suds to correctly parse the XML? Alternatively, the problem could be with the server. Is the XML not structured correctly?

My code is a follows (method names changed):

```
c = Client(url)  
p = c.factory.create('MyParam')  
p.value = 100  
c.service.run(p)
```

This results in a Suds exception:

```
File "/home/.../test.py", line 38, in test  
res = self.client.service.run(p)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py", line 539, in __call__
return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py", line 598, in invoke
result = self.send(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py", line 627, in send  
result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-py2.6.egg/suds/client.py", line   659, in succeeded  
r, p = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-py2.6.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 151, in get_reply  
result = self.replycomposite(rtypes, nodes)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/suds-0.3.9-  py2.6.egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 204, in replycomposite  
raise Exception('<%s/> not mapped to message part' % tag)  
Exception: <rval/> not mapped to message part
```

The returned XML (modified to remove customer identifiers)

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:getResponse xmlns:ns2="http://api.xxx.xxx.com/api/">
      <rval xmlns="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.com/api/">
        <ns2:totalNumEntries>
          2
        </ns2:totalNumEntries>
        <ns2:entries>
          <ns2:id>
            1
          </ns2:id>
        </ns2:entries>
        <ns2:entries>
          <ns2:id>
            2
          </ns2:id>
        </ns2:entries>
      </rval>
    </ns2:getResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible dup of [What does suds mean by "<faultcode/> not mapped to message part"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963094/what-does-suds-mean-by-faultcode-not-mapped-to-message-part/18948575#18948575)

Here is my answer from that question:

I had a similar issue where the call was successful, and Suds crashed on parsing the response from the client. The workaround I used was to use the [Suds option to return raw XML](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.options.Options-class.html) and then use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the response.

Example:

```
client = Client(url)
client.set_options(retxml=True)
soapresp_raw_xml = client.service.submit_func(data)
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(soapresp_raw_xml)
value_i_want = soup.find('ns:NewSRId')
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception actually means that the answer from SOAP-service contains tag `<rval>`, which doesn't exist in the WSDL-scheme of the service.

Keep in mind that the Suds library caches the WSDL-scheme, that is why the problem may occur if the WSDL-scheme was changed recently. Then the answers match the new scheme, but are verified by the suds-client with the old one. In this case `rm /tmp/suds/*` will help you.